# Issue with PCA - I want to plot the following set of data

Tags: python

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrDHc.png)

Comment: Please do not paste images of code. Paste whole code here inside code blocks (curcly braces in editor). Read [How-To-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Well the error pretty much explains itself: a numpy array doesn't have an index attribute.

I'm going to guess here, but if you meant to get the index of some value in a numpy array (similarly to what `index` does in plain python lists), you can use [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) like this:

```
idx = np.where(arr == 42) # or any other condition
```